# Setting source API address in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

Is it possible to "pretend" that a request is coming from a certain IP address (e.g. setting a fake X-Forwarded-For header) when rendering a page using puppeteer?

Comment: Is a proxy server an option? Cause you are able to launch Puppeteer with `args: [ '--proxy-server=your_proxy_address:port' ]`

Comment: Do you mean to set up a proxy? I would like to avoid having 1 more "unnecessary" component.

Comment: I mean like this: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/examples/proxy.js